# AngularJS, the variables doesn't change in the view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've created this simple calculation where the user inserts his levels and by that we get the combat calculation. But the problem is, the view never change, because the variables are somehow static. 
Please find jsfiddle for code.

`Code link :`[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvbjscp9/)

Comment: It would be good if you could also add some of the relevant code as part of your question itself as it would help other readers in the future,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

**First** using a model for each input element does not tell angular that you wish to capture the change events, in other words that you wish angular get notified when these element value has been changed. That's why you need to use the [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive, which role is to bind the new values to the DOM element.

The **second** issue is that angular does not know when the model values have been changed, until you do not tell to [watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) them.

Taking into account the above consideration this is how the refactored code should look like:

```
var app= angular.module("cmbtCalc", []);

app.controller('CombatCalculatorController', function($scope){
    $scope.result = 0;
    $scope.ALvl = 1 ;
    $scope.SLvl = 1 ;
    $scope.MLvl = 1 ;
    $scope.RLvl = 1 ;
    $scope.HLvl = 10 ;
    $scope.DLvl = 1 ;
    $scope.PLvl = 1 ;

    function RangeMage (real){
        return 0.325 * (Math.floor( real/ 2)+real); 
    };

    $scope.RealRange=RangeMage($scope.RLvl);
    $scope.RealMage=RangeMage($scope.MLvl);

    ['SLvl', 'ALvl', 'MLvl', 'RLvl', 'HLvl', 'DLvl', 'PLvl'].forEach(function(val) {
        $scope.$watch(val, function(newValue, oldValue) {
            $scope.melee = 0.325 * ($scope.ALvl + $scope.SLvl);
            $scope.base = 0.25 * ( $scope.DLvl + $scope.HLvl + Math.floor ($scope.PLvl / 2 ));
        })
    });

    $scope.calculatecmbt = function (){   
        $scope.result = Math.max($scope.melee, $scope.RealRange, $scope.RealMage) + $scope.base;  
        return $scope.result;   

    };
});
```

And inside your html you have to define a model for a ng-change directive:

```
<h2 ng-model="RealRang" ng-change="calculatecmbt">
{{result}}
{{calculatecmbt() | number}}
</h2>
```

And here is the working code: https://jsfiddle.net/tvbjscp9/5/

Answer (score 0):

I think you does not invoke the function [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shankarrjg/tvbjscp9/2/)

You may have use function invoke on input changed or else use watchers for invoke functions

```
$scope.$watch('myVar', function(newValue, oldValue) {// You can invoke your custom functions here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will need to call calculatecmbt on change of value and save the output in scope variable that you bind on UI.

```
    <p>Insert your Prayer Level  <input type="number" ng-model="PLvl" ng-change="calculatecmbt()"></p>
    {{outputVal}}
```

Controller code

```
$scope.outputVal = Math.max($scope.melee, $scope.RealRange, $scope.RealMage) + $scope.base;        
  return $scope.outputVal;        
};
```

Answer (score -2):

I made it work, wasn't passing the function values. Here's the working code :)asdasdasdas

```
[Working jsfiddle]( https://jsfiddle.net/tvbjscp9/8/)!
```

Comment: oto260 that does not seem to be working? Are we missing something?

Comment: Fixed the Link, should be working, added strings for the classes as well, ignore the text message